# Async calls in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

how to implement a wait async call in a while controller in jmeter. any pointers would be appreciated. I am sending post requests in concurrency thread group. If I put a while controller with the concurrency thread group its not sending concurrent requests to the application.it waits till the while controller is done( the while controller basically checks whether the data is persisted - which is working) . The test plan built so far is .
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Each JMeter thread (virtual user) executes Samplers upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))
2. JMeter waits for response from previous [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) before starting a new one
3. [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) executes its children until the function or variable you put in the "Condition" area resolves to `true`

If your While Controller is just doing some form of monitoring and the output of its children Samplers work is not required for the next iteration of the `Post Anomaly` sampler - consider moving it into a separate [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) or put it under [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) so it would be executed i.e. by 1 thread only.